# tee function from itertools library

Tags: python, python-itertools

Both list and islice objects are iterable but why this difference in result.

```
r = [1, 2, 3, 4]               
i1, i2 = tee(r)
print [e for e in r if e < 3]
print [e for e in i2]
#[1, 2]
#[1, 2, 3, 4]


r = islice(count(), 1, 5)          
i1, i2 = tee(r)
print [e for e in r if e < 3]
print [e for e in i2]
#[1, 2]
#[]
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The issue here is that `tee()` needs to consume the values from the original iterator, if you start consuming them from the original iterator, it will be unable to function correctly. In your list example, the iteration simply begins again. In the generator example, it is exhausted and no more values are produced.

This is well documented:

> Once tee() has made a split, the original iterable should not be used anywhere else; otherwise, the iterable could get advanced without the tee objects being informed.

[Source](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee)

Edit to illustrate the point in the difference between a list and a generator:

```
>>> from itertools import islice, count
>>> a = list(range(5))
>>> b = islice(count(), 0, 5)
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b
<itertools.islice object at 0x7fabc95d0fc8>
>>> for item in a:
...     print(item)
... 
0
1
2
3
4
>>> for item in a:
...     print(item)
... 
0
1
2
3
4
>>> for item in b:
...     print(item)
... 
0
1
2
3
4
>>> for item in b:
...     print(item)
... 
>>>
```

Comment: but list object and islice object needs to behave similarly, right?

Comment: @John No, when you loop over the list, you get a new iterator each time, meaning you still get the values. When you use `islice()` you get a generator, which will produce the values once, and then be exhausted. Try it yourself - just loop over a list twice, then take an islice and loop over that twice - note the difference in behaviour.

Comment: @John To make the two examples behave similarly, use `r = iter([1,2,3,4])` rather than `r = [1,2,3,4]`.

Comment: If you destroy iterators from the tee, can you advance the original iterator ?

Answer (score 0):

In your list comprehensions, you want to replace `r` with `i1`.